# Is there any method other than pthread_create to assign work to the same thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

In Pthread programming we can assign task to the work threads by calling pthread_create function and also pass the function argument but I want to assign the job to the previously created thread by using pthread_create what can i do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "communicate" a new task to existing threads. Let existing threads wait for a signal (using  pthread_cond_wait()). When you have a new task, you can store the task in a common storage, and then simply signal the worker threads (using pthtread_cond_signal()). This approach works well, when you have a pool of worker threads that are waiting for incoming tasks. When you signal, only one thread will wake up (the pthread_cond_wait is tied to a mutex and so only one of them re-acquires the mutex) and the remaining threads will continue to wait.